# NSfetchedResultsController changes not reflecting to UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Problem with `NSFetchedResultsController` is that I fetched the data and it populates the `UITableView` with `cacheName` set to `nil`. Later when I change the `predicate` of `NSFetchedResultsController` and called `perfromFetch`, it won't refreshes the `UITableView` however the data inside `NSFetchedResultsController` is updated. One thing more, `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods are also not invoking.

Thanks in Advance.

## Edited: Added Code

## NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

## NSFetchedResultsController

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [GmailDBService sharedService].managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Thread"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"historyId" ascending:NO];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(messages, $m, ANY $m.labels.identifier == %@).@count > 0", self.label.identifier];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

## Predicate Refreshing

```
- (IBAction)unwindToThreadsController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@", @"15f1919682399cc9"];
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
}
```

Comment: have u set the NSFetchedResultsController delegate as self ??

Comment: Yes I did and cross check the value later. Delegate is intact and is same as before.

Comment: Can you post some code it is very difficult to assume what might be happening in your project. Posting the relevant part of the code will help us suggest you better solution

Comment: I have posted the code, Please have a look.

Comment: Code looks fine. You sure FetchedResultsController delegate is not getting called only after updating predicate ?? Finally you sure the data in FetchedResultsController's fetched object changing on changing predicate ??

Comment: Yes i'm dead sure. I have logged them.

Answer (score 1):

`fetchedResultsController` are not expensive. You should not be afraid to create and destroy them as needed.  When you need to change the predicate discard the current `fetchedResultsController` and create a new one. Don't forget to reload the tableView after you do so.

The changes aren't triggering the `fetchedResultsController` because you are monitoring threads, but your predicate is based on messages.  So when a message is changed it does not trigger a change in the `fetchedResultsController`.  The controller only monitors changes to one entity and does not expect changes to other entities to effect it. You can fix this in a few ways:

1. setup your `fetchedResultsController` to look at message and group them by threads, then only display every section (ie thread) as a row.
2. every time you change a message also change its thread (message.thread.threadId = message.thread.threadId  will count as a change as far as the `fetchedResultsController` is concerned).

Also `fetchBatchSize` isn't respected by a `fetchedResultsController` so you should remove it for clarity.